# Trouble switching the project CRS in a new project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, error, coordinate-system

I'm trying to change the project CRS from WGS 84 to NAD83/ UTM Zone 17N. However QGS will not let me and an error pops up. The text from the error is:

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
_core.QgsCsException: forward transform of (inf, inf) Error: Fallback transform failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\go2streetview\go2streetview.py", line 466, in setPosition
    actualSRS = self.transformToCurrentSRS(actualWGS84)
  File "C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\go2streetview\go2streetview.py", line 623, in transformToCurrentSRS
    return xform.transform(pPoint) # forward transformation: src -> dest
_core.QgsCsException: forward transform of
(inf, inf)
Error: Fallback transform failed


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.14.16-Pi Pi, df27394552 

Python Path:
C:/Users/haile/DOWNLO~1/GEOG36~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/Users/haile/DOWNLO~1/GEOG36~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\Users\haile\Downloads\Geog 366\bin\python37.zip
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Users\haile\Downloads\Geog 366\bin
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\haile\DOWNLO~1\GEOG36~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/haile/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\go2streetview
C:\Users\haile\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\go2streetview\res
C:\Users\haile\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\HCMGIS/forms
```

Another error also pops up when I add the layer I want and change that CRS from WGS 84 to NAD83/ UTM Zone 17N:
An alternative, ballpark-only transform was used when transforming coordinates between EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and EPSG:26917 - NAD83 / UTM zone 17N. The results may not match those obtained by using the preferred operation:
Possibly an incorrect choice of operation was made for transformations between these reference systems. Check the Project Properties and ensure that the selected transform operations are applicable over the whole extent of the current project.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling to see if that would help, I have also used both 3.12 and 3.14 to see if the version was the issue. My classmates have been able to switch the same project CRS without any issues on their PCs.

[image: This is the first error I mentioned]
[image: This is the second error I mentioned]

Comment: Disable the go2streetview plugin and [report an issue](https://github.com/enricofer/go2streetview/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give it a try after disabling the go2street and HCMGIS plugins.